# Group by children

Tags: javascript, json

i have `json` like

```
 [
   { up: 0, id: 1, name: "男裝", level: 1, children:[] },
   { up: 0, id: 2, name: "女裝", level: 1, children: []},
   { up: 1, id: 3, name: "上衣", level: 2, children: []},
   { up: 2, id: 4, name: "上衣", level: 2, children: []},
   { up: 3, id: 5, name: "T穴", level: 3, children: [] },
   { up: 4, id: 6, name: "襯衫", level: 3, children: []},
 ]
```

I want  to

```
 { 
   up: 0, 
   id: 1, 
   name: "男裝", 
   level: 1, 
   children: [
           { 
             up: 1, 
             id: 3, 
             name: "上衣", 
             level: 2, 
             children: [{up: 3, id: 5, name: "T穴", level: 3, children: []}]
           }]
 },

 { 
   up: 0, 
   id: 2, 
   name: "女裝", 
   level: 1, 
   children: [
          { 
            up: 2, 
            id: 4, 
            name: "上衣", 
            level: 2, 
            children: [{ up: 4, id: 6, name: "襯衫", level: 3, children: [] }]
          }]
 }
```

I tried to group like this, but it didn't work

Comment: that's not json. that's just javascript. And we are not here to bang out code for you. Show what YOU'VE done to attempt this, we'll (maybe) try help fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `forEach()` loop and inside you also need to use one recursive function that will search each element that is already added to result and its children until it finds object with id that is == to up value of current object in loop.

```js
var data =  [
  { up: 0, id: 1, name: "男裝", level: 1, children:[] },
  { up: 0, id: 2, name: "女裝", level: 1, children: []},
  { up: 1, id: 3, name: "上衣", level: 2, children: []},
  { up: 2, id: 4, name: "上衣", level: 2, children: []},
  { up: 3, id: 5, name: "T穴", level: 3, children: [] },
  { up: 4, id: 6, name: "襯衫", level: 3, children: []},
];

var result = [];

data.forEach(function(e) {
  if (e.up == 0) {
    result.push(e);
  } else {
    function group(input) {
      input.forEach(function(a) {
        if (a.id == e.up) {
          a.children.push(e);
        } else if (a.children.length) {
          group(a.children);
        }
      })
    }
    group(result)
  }
})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: OMG  ur  god    thx   for this

Answer (score 0):

When describing something like this, it's generally useful to state very simply, or with a little pseudo code, what you're trying to do. Going through that exercise often reveals a solution. Post as little as possible to make your point clear.

If I had to guess, I'd say you want to create N number of top-level branches (depending on how many level 1s you have). Each object would contain an array with a higher "level" object in it.

The new top level array would look like (leaving out irrelevant props):

```
[ 
  { level: 1, children [ 
    { level: 2, children [ 
      { level: 3, children [] } 
    ] } 
  ] },
  { level: 1, children [ 
    { level: 2, children [ 
      { level: 3, children [] } 
    ] } 
  ] } 
]
```

If that's what you mean, then sure somebody could help you write that, it's not hard.

But...will you always have enough objects to evenly distribute through levels? Will a level ever be skipped? Can you have varying counts of "levels" (for instance, 3 level 2s, 7 level 4s)? And so on? Will you be altering this structure with insertions, deletions, etc?

To address this, you should be thinking not in terms of "write me the code to do this," but "what is the best data structure to create this kind of relationship, such that I can do adds/edits/deletes/lookups without a lot of mess?"

I highly, strongly, adamantly recommend you spend a little time reading about basic data structures: dictionary, array, and how they can be used to build Trees and Linked Lists.

That'll get you what you want. Other than that I'm happy to implement the code to achieve your base case regardless of whether or not it is actually useful, once we get my hourly fee out of the way :)

Comment: Thank you for your response I will continue to work hard